# Oracle SQL - How to get diff between values in same row, no unique ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning Oracle SQL.

I need to determine the time between each purchased/return transaction for a given product.

A sample of the data is shown below. There is no unique transaction identifier linking the purchase with the return however, I can assume the return immediately following the purchase (based on transactiontime) is the same transaction.

Can you please let me know how do go about solving this? A sample SQL statement would be greatly appreciated.

```
Product TransactionType  TransactionTime
A       PURCHASE         18-Aug-17 10.15.56.000000 AM
A       RETURN           18-Aug-17 10.30.21.000000 AM
A       PURCHASE         18-Aug-17 11.10.35.000000 AM
A       RETURN           18-Aug-17 11.12.52.000000 AM
B       PURCHASE         18-Aug-17 10.15.56.000000 AM
B       RETURN           18-Aug-17 10.22.56.000000 AM
B       PURCHASE         18-Aug-17 10.30.21.000000 AM
B       RETURN           18-Aug-17 10.31.21.000000 AM
```

Comment: can you show the expected output as well?

Comment: You may be oversimplifying the problem. One would assume that not all products that are purchased are necessarily returned. So the table should have, say, 50 rows with product = A and type = PURCHASE and only three rows with product = A and type = RETURN. Perhaps you can assume that for each RETURN the corresponding PURCHASE is the one immediately preceding it. (This assumes also that there are no consecutive rows with RETURN, which may easily happen in real life.) Why don't your transactions have a transaction ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (next_ttime - transactiontime) as time_to_return
from (select t.*,
             lead(transactiontype) over (partition by product order by transactiontime) as next_ttype,
             lead(transactiontime) over (partition by product order by transactiontime) as next_ttime
      from t
     ) t
where transactiontype = 'PURCHASE' and
      next_ttype = 'RETURN'
```